# How do you provide a pointcut bound annotation to an advice method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

So I've defined pointcuts for all methods and all classes of a particular annotation... what I want to do is retrieve the annotation value on every method call. Here is what I have so far

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* my.stuff..*(..))")
    private void allMethods(){}

    @Pointcut("within(@my.stuff.MyAnnotation*)")
    private void myAnnotations(){}

    @Pointcut("allMethods() && myAnnotations()")
    private void myAnnotatedClassMethods(){}

    @Before("myAnnotatedClassMethods()")
    private void beforeMyAnnotatedClassMethods(){
        System.out.println("my annotated class method detected.");
        // I'd like to be able to access my class level annotation's value here.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have Spring AOP supply the value of the annotation annotating your target object's class.

You'll have to use the [binding forms documented in the specification](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing) and propagate an argument across your `@Pointcut` methods.

For example

```
@Pointcut("execution(* my.stuff..*(..))")
private void allMethods() {
}

@Pointcut("@within(myAnnotation)")
private void myAnnotations(MyAnnotation myAnnotation) {
}

@Pointcut("allMethods() && myAnnotations(myAnnotation)")
private void myAnnotatedClassMethods(MyAnnotation myAnnotation) {
}

@Before("myAnnotatedClassMethods(myAnnotation)")
private void beforeMyAnnotatedClassMethods(MyAnnotation myAnnotation){
    System.out.println("my annotated class method detected: " + myAnnotation);
}
```

Spring, starting from the `myAnnotations` pointcut, will match the name given in `@within` with a method parameter and use that to determine the annotation type. That is then propagated down to the `beforeMyAnnotatedClassMethods` advice through the `myAnnotatedClassMethods` pointcut.

The Spring AOP stack will then lookup the annotation value before invoking your `@Before` method and pass it as an argument.

---

An alternative, if you don't like the solution above, is to simply provide a [`JoinPoint`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) parameter in your advice method. You can use it to resolve the `target` instance with [`getTarget`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getTarget%28%29) and use that value to get the class annotation. For example,

```
@Before("myAnnotatedClassMethods()")
private void beforeMyAnnotatedClassMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("my annotated class method detected: " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class));
}
```

I'm unsure how this will behave if the target is further wrapped in other proxies. The annotation might be "hidden" behind proxy classes. Use it carefully.